# From FizzBuzz to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, fizzbuzz

I cannot seem to figure this out whatsoever, I can use console.log(i) and get the return but cant figure out how to return as an array?

Takes a number, max and returns an array that contains every number from
0 to max (not inclusive) that is divisible by either 3 or 5, but not both

```
    function fizzBuzz(max) {
  let arr = [];
  
    for(let i = 0; i < max; i++){
        if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 7 !== 0){
          arr = arr.concat(i);
          
        } else if(i % 3 !== 0 && i % 7 === 0){
          arr = arr.concat(i);
   }
  return arr;
};
fizzBuzz(20);
```

Comment: You should properly format your code. You'll notice a missing closing `}`.

Comment: If you add the missing `}` it does return `[3, 6, 7, 9, 12, 14, 15, 18]`. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (which is used to add an element to an array) rather than [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (which is used to merge an array with another array) is much simpler here. You can also use the XOR operator (`^`) instead of writing two `if` statements:

```js
function fizzBuzz(max) {
  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 ^ i % 5 === 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(fizzBuzz(20));
```

Comment: This seems to produce the opposite output from what the OP wants: _"returns an array that contains every number from 0 to max (not inclusive) that is divisible by either 3 or 5, but not both"_.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. Fixed both errors.

Comment: @UnholySheep it is. `(!A && B) || (A && !B)` is strictly equivalent to `A ^ B`.

Comment: Thanks, learned something. Didn't even know that something like a XOR operator exists!

Comment: wow thanks guys, never heard of a XOR operator either, makes it much simpler

Answer (score 2):

Few things wrong in your code, you should use array.push instead of concat and you were missing a `}` at the end.

This code should do what you need :)
produces an array between 0 and max inclusive and produces an array of numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5 but not both

```js
function fizzBuzz(max) {
  let arr = [];  
  for(let i = 0; i <= max; i++){
    if((!(i % 3) && !(i % 5))) continue;
    if(!(i % 3) || !(i % 5)){
      arr.push(i);
    }         
  }
  return arr;
};
console.log(fizzBuzz(20));
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the condition. 15 should not be among the output numbers.

Comment: @WaisKamal absolutely right, I've fixed it now :)